# java new line replacement

Tags: java, newline, replaceall

I am wondering about why I don't get the expected result with this one:

```
String t = "1302248663033   <script language='javascript'>nvieor\ngnroeignrieogi</script>";
t.replaceAll("\n", "");
System.out.println(t);
```

The output is:

```
1302248663033   <script language='javascript'>nvieor
gnroeignrieogi</script>
```

So I am wondering why `\n` is still there. Anybody knows? Is \n special in someway?

EDIT:

So I was having trouble with matching the newline character with a . in a regex expression, not realizing that one use to use the DOTALL option, so I'll add what one needs to do here for future reference:

```
String text = null;
text = FileUtils.readFileToString(inFile);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<script language='javascript'>.+?</script>\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
text = p.matcher(text).replaceAll("");
out.write(text);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  String operations like `replaceAll` don't modify the instance you call it with, they return new String instances.  The solution is to assign the modified string to your original variable.

```
t = t.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Comment: To be portable between OSes, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in lieu of linefeed character.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `\n` is special. It is an escape sequence that stands for a newline.
You need to escape it in a string literal in order for it to be actually interpreted the way you want. Append a \ before the sequence so that it looks like this:

```
"\\n"
```

Now your program should look like this:

```
String t = "1302248663033   <script language='javascript'>nvieor\\ngnroeignrieogi</script>";
t = t.replaceAll("\\n", "");
System.out.println(t);
```

Of course if the string `t` is coming from somewhere rather than actually being typed by you into the program then you need only add the extra slash in your call to `replaceAll()`

Edited according to comments.

Comment: I missed the other error everyone else has pointed out. You do need to take the result of the `replaceAll()` call and use that, not the original string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String escape(String s) {
    return s
            .replaceAll("\n", "")
            .replaceAll("\r", "");
}
```